# Mecrisp-Stellaris Forth on TI Tiva C LaunchPad

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, programming, texas-instruments

I'm currently trying to load [mecrisp](http://mecrisp.sourceforge.net/) forth on a spare tiva c series launchpad (TM4C123) board I have at home and am not having much success. I'm an electrical engineering student and while I've programmed boards using IDE's such as crossworks before I've never done so from scratch. I have the board hooked up via USB, and have attempted programming the board using TI's LM Flash programmer but haven't had much luck. I guess I'm hoping for a general understanding of the programming process and any gotchas people are aware of that might cause issues.
As I understand it I do the following.

1. Download mecrisp stellaris
2. Program my board using USB and a TI utility
3. Connect to the Forth interpreter via TeraTerm

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: In particular I appear unable to program FORTH onto the microcontroller and establish a connection via serial terminal to the programmed device. I am unsure if it is due to an error in programming the device or a serial connection problem. My question was broadly posed in an attempt to cover any basic errors I might be making. Ideally a simple getting started tutorial would be available but after reading through the mecrisp documentation and extensive googling I am unable to find an example for my specific board.

Comment: Why not try TIs free IDE, Code Composer Studio?

Comment: you have not provided adequate information ... it is unclear what the actual problem is ... are you able to load and run a simple "hello world!" program or an LED blink program? ... if you are unable to do that, then you should not be asking about forth

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tyler, I was under the impression that I had to use a programming utility to load Forth for some reason.

Comment: @Fuzzy_Bunnys, CCS includes a programming utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sequence allowed me to program my Tiva C series board for the TM4C123 chip.

1. Download Mecrisp-Stellaris
2. Download TI's Uniflash
3. Connect the Tiva C series board via usb and the debug port
4. Load mecrisp-stellaris-lm4f120.bin using Uniflash on to the board
5. Make a connection at 115200 baud rate via TeraTerm to the launchpad board.
6. Reset the board and the welcome message for mecrisp stellaris should appear.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, my Mecrisp-Across documentation site has some info on installing Mecrisp-Stellaris to the Tiva that may help:
https://mecrisp-across-folkdoc.sourceforge.io/installing.html#installing

Comment: thank you terry! Very helpful